# How to display documents from URL without external app?

Tags: android, url, document

In my app I am getting URLs of the documents, and I want to display them in my app, not in any external app.

This is the code I have used.

```
public class Doc_webview extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener{
    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;
String tag="doc";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doc_webview);
        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Log.e(tag,"url "+Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("URL")).toString());
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("URL")).toString());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.e(tag,"page started "+url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) {
        Log.e(tag,"page finished "+url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.e(tag,"page error "+description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Log.e(tag,"download started "+url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {
        Log.e(tag,"page request "+url);
    }
}
```

**I only want to display them, not open them for editing.**

Comment: You need to create a web view and then open the url by adding the link before your url http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=yoururl
*in place of yoururl add the link of the document

Comment: @RakshitNawani tried. not working

Comment: show your code, it is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am using this code to open a document in my webview

```
    public class ToSite extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        Utils.setShared(this);
        String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

        System.out.println(url);

        if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "URL not Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and my url is

http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://52.24.60.37/guilt/uploads/termcondition/profile60252550.pdf

Google Doc URL : http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=\

My Doc URL : http://52.24.60.37/guilt/uploads/termcondition/profile60252550.pdf

appending both the URL to open the Document in WebView

Comment: I am getting 500 error. This is my url http:\\\\\\\\192.168.1.99\\\\webtriage\\\\clientsfiles\\\\CLT0000558//Aniruddha_Basak.doc   this is working fine when i am directly opening this link in pc chrome but in webview it is going to google search and when i tried your way. It is showing 500 error.

Comment: Let me check what I can do about it

Comment: @SachinMalik : Why is there extra "\\"in your code  ?
Google Docs might get confused in opening that link

Comment: @SachinMalik : If you are getting the URL from server change the name of the file like in answer, it will work fine for you

Comment: it is coming from server and i am parsing the url after parsing it becomes this http:\\192.168.1.99\webtriage\clientsfiles\CLT0000023//bill.pdf

Comment: Well according to the docs it should open perfectly. Can you print the whole URL which you are opening because I am not able to open the Local URL in my System.

Comment: @SachinMalik : change your "\"with "/". I think it will work fine then

Comment: Open this link your Local browser and tell me if it opens the Page in View https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://192.168.1.99/webtriage/clientsfiles/CLT0000023//bill.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110817/discussion-between-rakshit-nawani-and-sachin-malik).